# How many singular values does a matrix with $l$ linearly dependent vectors have?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix with $l$ linearly dependent column vectors, where $1 \leq l \leq min\{m,n\}$. How many singular values greater than $0$ does A have?

My answer would be $min\{m,n-l\}$, but I am unsure about it.

Comment: Sorry, I misformulated that, I just edited my question.

Comment: people on this site prefer that you show the work behind an attempt.  I'd suggest looking at $\text{rank}(A)$ and applying SVD.